# Can this ‘function’, similar to a factorial but divides numbers instead, be useful?

Tags: factorial

$n!$ is where n is multiplied in this format:

$n•(n-1)•(n-2)•\ldots1$.

It has many uses and so in this way, would this ‘function’:

$n/(n-1)/(n-2)/\ldots/1$,

have an actual use in mathematics?

Comment: If what you mean is, $n$ divided by $n-1$, then the result divided by $n-2$ and so on, then wouldn't this just be $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$?

Comment: We cannot generalize a quotient to more than two entries like a sum or a product, but as you see you can easily formulate this expression with the help of the factorial. Whether this particular expression is of any use, is another story.